# php and using composition

Tags: php

So I have the following which errors out but it seems like php should recognize that it only needs only one copy. Should I create this as a reference to remove cirucular instantion of new objects?

```
<?php
class A {
   public function __construct(){
      echo "within A<br />";
      $this->b=new &B();
   }
 }

 class B{
     public function __construct(){
       echo "within B<br />";
       $this->a=new A();
 }
}  

$jt=new A();
$ar=new B();
```

thx

---

edit - ? could have been asked better. I'm aware of most of issues brought up. Will move to static functions.

Comment: when you do `new …()` you tell php to create a new object with the type of that class. how is it supposed to know that you only want a single instance of B? (hint: use the singleton pattern)

Comment: You probably want to pass either the `A` object to `B` or vice versa as a constructor parameter, not unconditionally create new instances of the other class in the constructor.

Comment: And it needs to be `$this->b =& new B();`

Comment: Objects are always references. `&` is not required (and recommend) anymore in nearly all cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
<?php
class A {
  public function __construct(){
     echo "within A<br />";
  }

  public function setB(B $b) {
    $this->b = $b;
  }
}

class B{
    public function __construct(A $a){
         echo "within B<br />";
         $this->a = $a;
    }
}  

$a=new A();
$b=new B($a);
$a->setB($b);
```

As others already mentioned in the comments:

- You don't need `&` as objects are always references
- PHP can't know what you want, new always creates a new object
- If you want to limit the numebr of objects of a class use the singleton pattern

Comment: I agree with most of this, but Singletons are controversial.  I wouldn't go quite so far as to say you should never use them, but you should certainly use them sparingly.  In most cases you don't need singletons, just a bit of care.

Comment: @Gordon, correct, they somehow replace global variables. I personally use them once in a while, but of course, you should not mess up your whole project with Singletons.